# Apply loop for rollapply windows

Tags: r, zoo

I currently have a dataset with 50,000+ rows of data for which I need to find rolling sums. I have completed this using `rollaply` which has worked perfectly. I need to apply these rolling sums across a range of widths (600, 1200, 1800...6000) which I have done by cut and pasting each line of script and changing the width. While it works, I'd like to tidy my script but applying a loop, or similar, if possible so that once the `rollapply` function has completed it's first 'pass' at 600 width, it then completes the same with 1200 and so on. Example:

```
Var1  Var2    Var3
1     11      19
43    12      1
4     13      47
21    14      29
41    15      42
16    16      5
17    17      16
10    18      15
20    19      41
44    20      27

width_2 <- rollapply(x$Var1, FUN = sum, width = 2)
width_3 <- rollapply(x$Var1, FUN = sum, width = 3)
width_4 <- rollapply(x$Var1, FUN = sum, width = 4)
```

Is there a way to run widths 2, 3, then 4 in a simpler way rather than cut and paste, particularly when I have up to 10 widths, and then need to run this across other cols. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` in `base R`

```
lst1 <- lapply(2:4, function(i) rollapply(x$Var1, FUN = sum, width = i))
names(lst1) <- paste0('width_', 2:4)
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

NOTE: It is not recommended to create multiple objects in the global environment.  Instead, the `list` would be better

---

Or with a `for` loop

```
for(v in 2:4) {
   assign(paste0('width_', v), rollapply(x$Var1, FUN = sum, width = v))  
  }
```

---

Create a function to do this for multiple dataset

```
 f1 <- function(col1, i) {
          rollapply(col1, FUN = sum, width = i)
     }
 
 lapply(x[c('Var1', 'Var2')], function(x) lapply(2:4, function(i)
            f1(x, i)))
```

Comment: Given that my actual windows are multiples of 600, would this then change to: 
`for(v in 600:6000) 
{ assign(paste0('width_', v), rollapply(x$Var1, FUN = sum, width = v))`

Comment: I just tried the above comment, and while it works for the example, when I extrapolate it to my actual data, it applies the function to every width 600:6000. Can I make that work so that it only applies for MULTIPLES of 600 i.e. 600, 1200, 1800, 2400....6000?
Edit: added a simple vector of widths `c(600, 1200, 1800....)` and worked perfectly

Comment: rollapply already works on every column so there is no need for an extra lappy over columns.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating separate vectors in global environment probably you can add these as new columns in the already existing dataframe.

Note that `rollaplly(..., FUN = sum)` is same as `rollsum`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

bind_cols(x, purrr::map_dfc(2:4,
 ~x %>% transmute(!!paste0('Var1_roll_', .x) := rollsumr(Var1, .x, fill = NA))))

#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var1_roll_2 Var1_roll_3 Var1_roll_4
#1     1   11   19          NA          NA          NA
#2    43   12    1          44          NA          NA
#3     4   13   47          47          48          NA
#4    21   14   29          25          68          69
#5    41   15   42          62          66         109
#6    16   16    5          57          78          82
#7    17   17   16          33          74          95
#8    10   18   15          27          43          84
#9    20   19   41          30          47          63
#10   44   20   27          64          74          91
```

You can use `seq` to generate the variable window size.

```
seq(600, 6000, 600)
#[1]  600 1200 1800 2400 3000 3600 4200 4800 5400 6000
```

Comment: This solution is more suitable for the issue than only using `lapply()` or loops that also can be found in other answers in SO!